# Using JGit to create a tool that clones repositories out of properties

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm about to develop a tool that reads out a properties file and then creates folders out of it and pulls the repositories out of those URLs.

Actually I managed to let it create a folder/subfolder and clone one project into it:

```
File repoOne = new File("repositories/repo1");
Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI("https://github.com/xetra11/renderay.git")
        .setDirectory(repoOne)
        .call();
```

When I run this a second time I receive the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Destination path "repo1" already exists and is not an empty directory
```

I don't really understand why JGit tries to overwrite the existing directory. I know that recloning there is senseless - but what bothers me is that JGit is not about to just "move" into this folder and execute the command. I'm about to execute a `FetchCommand` in the already existing repositories. In the current state, I assume JGit will always tell me the directory already exists.

Any ideas how to let him simply execute the command within the folder IF it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a folder as the local destination of a clone, it must either not exist or be empty.

You would probably want to detect if a repository exists in a given folder and then only fetch new changes and otherwise clone.

In order to determine if a repository exists, use this code:

```
FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
repositoryBuilder.setGitDir( folder );
Repository repository = repositoryBuilder.build();
boolean repositoryExists = repository.getRef( "HEAD" ) != null );
```

Now you can either clone, or fetch, depending on whether the repository exists or not.

For a more detailed discussion about accessing repositories with JGit see here: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/

Comment: I have a problem with this way to actually create a "non-bare" repository. `Git.init().setDirectory(dirPath).call()` gives me a "non-bare" but I have not found a way to check if the repository has been already created.

Comment: Depending on what the _folder_ represents, you may need to use `BaseRepositoryBuilder::setWorkTree()` instead of `::setGirDir()` The article mentioned in the answer discusses git dir vs. work dir and how to detect if a repository was created in length.

Answer (score 0):

Test if the repo (directory) already exists and handle it appropriately:

```
File repoOne = new File("repositories/repo1");
if (repoOne.exists()) {
  // Check if it's a repo or do something else.
} else {
  // Repository doesn't exist, create it.
}
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.